# MySQL Procedure Error on Creation

Tags: mysql, procedure

Creating a procedure below and it keeps giving out about assigning values fro the first select statement, am I doing it completely wrong, any help greatly appreciated.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= `m
>   id`, vCurrentVote := vote FROM td_voted WHERE id = pCid LIMIT 1;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_update_vote (IN pCid INT, IN pVote INT, IN pMid INT, OUT pNewVote INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE vMid, vVote, vCurrentVote, vNewVote INT;

    IF pVote = 1 THEN
        SET vVote = 1;
    ELSE
        SET vVote = -1;
    END IF;

    SELECT vMid := `mid`, vCurrentVote := vote FROM td_voted WHERE id = pCid LIMIT 1;

    IF vMid <> pMid THEN
        SELECT vVoteType := vote 
        FROM td_votes 
        WHERE `mid` = vMid 
        AND cid = pCid 
        LIMIT 1;

        IF vVoteType NOT NULL OR vVoteType <> vVote THEN
            UPDATE td_votes 
            SET vote = vVote, 
            updated = NOW()
            WHERE cid = pCid
            AND `mid` = pMid
            LIMIT 1;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO td_votes (`mid`, cid, vote)
            VALUES (pMid, pCid, vVote);
        END IF;

        vNewVote = vCurrentVote + vVote;

        UPDATE td_voted
        SET vote = vNewVote
        WHERE id = pCid
        LIMIT 1;

        SELECT pNewVote := vote FROM td_voted WHERE id = pCid LIMIT 1;
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Solved it, updated the question with the working solution.

Comment: Instead of updating the question with your solution add your own answer as a solution found and tick it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me after much debugging.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_update_vote (IN pCid INT, IN pVote INT, IN pMid INT, OUT pNewVote INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE vMid, vVote, vCurrentVote, vNewVote INT;

    IF pVote = 1 THEN
        SET vVote = 1;
    ELSE
        SET vVote = -1;
    END IF;

    SELECT vMid = `mid`, vCurrentVote = vote FROM td_voted WHERE id = pCid LIMIT 1;

    IF vMid <> pMid THEN
        SELECT vVoteType = vote 
        FROM td_votes 
        WHERE `mid` = vMid 
        AND cid = pCid 
        LIMIT 1;

        IF (vVoteType IS NOT NULL) OR (vVoteType <> vVote) THEN
            UPDATE td_votes 
            SET vote = vVote, 
            updated = NOW()
            WHERE cid = pCid
            AND `mid` = pMid
            LIMIT 1;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO td_votes (`mid`, cid, vote)
            VALUES (pMid, pCid, vVote);
        END IF;

        SET vNewVote = vCurrentVote + vVote;

        UPDATE td_voted
        SET vote = vNewVote
        WHERE id = pCid
        LIMIT 1;

        SELECT pNewVote = vote FROM td_voted WHERE id = pCid LIMIT 1;
    END IF;
END
```